# Evento Onchange para dos inputs distintos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola amigos tengo una serie de `input` que se van llenando poco a poco , pero tengo dos en particular de los que quisiera hacer un calculo, entonces mi pregunta es como puedo usar **onchange** o algo similar en js para que cuando el estado de ambos cambie me ejecute otro metodo

```html
 <input type="text" id="capacidadPago" name="name" value="" />
 
  <input type="text" id="capacidadRenta" name="name" value="" />

 <input type="text" id="respuesta" name="name" value="" />
```

de modo que cuando **capacidadPago** y **capacidadrenta** cambien su valor de vuelva la suma de ambos en el input respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto podría servir

```
function actualizarRespuesta(){
    var capacidadPago = $("#capacidadPago").val();
    var capacidadRenta = $("#capacidadRenta").val();

    $("#respuesta").val(parseInt(capacidadPago)+parseInt(capacidadRenta);
}

 $("#capacidadPago").change(actualizarRespuesta)
 $("#capacidadRenta").change(actualizarRespuesta)
```

Desde la linea 1 a la 6 es el listener del evento onchange.
Las lineas 2 y 3 son para recuperar el valor de los inputs capacidadPago y capacidadRenta de acuerdo a su id.
La linea 5 es para asignar la suma de los valores recuperados en las lineas 2 y 3, previa conversion a int (paraeInt), al input cuyo id es respuesta.
Por ultimo las lineas 8 y 9 son para asignar el listener a los inputs capacidadPago y capacidadRenta.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, le he agregado una explicación

Comment: la he editado, a como me sirvió a mi y creo que fue la mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Número 1: <input type="text" id="numero1" />
    <br><br>
    Número 2: <input type="text" id="numero2" />
    <br><br>
    Resultado: <input type="text" disabled id="resultado">
    <br><br>
    
    
    <script>
        let numero1 = document.getElementById("numero1")
        let numero2 = document.getElementById("numero2")
        let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado")
        
        numero1.addEventListener("change", () => {
          resultado.value = numero1.value
          numero2.addEventListener("change", () => {
            resultado.value = parseInt(numero1.value) + parseInt(numero2.value)
          })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Explicación**:

- Obtenemos por su **`id`** a cada uno de los **`inputs`**; tanto los que recibirán los números tecleados por el usuario, como aquel en el cual se escribirá el resultado
- Del primer número le agrego un **`listener`** en el evento **`change`** para detectar cuando su estado *cambió* y entonces asignarle en su propiedad **`value`** el valor de dicho **`input`** a la caja de **`resultado`**
- Dentro del mismo contexto de la **`arrow function`** del **`numero1`** detectamos el evento **`change`** pero ahora de **`numero2`**
- Pasado el punto anterior, ya estamos en condiciones de sumar los **`values`** de cada cada de texto y se lo asignamos al input que tiene el id **`resultado`**
- Pasamos por la función **`parseInt()`** a cada uno de los **`inputs`** para evitar que se *concatenen* y en su lugar se sumen